# I have 2 buttons English and Arabic for changing the language if the user wants. Pressing 2 buttons the language is changing in all activities

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons English and Arabic for changing the language if the user wants.  Pressing those 2 buttons the language is changing in all activities for that I implemented code but in this language is not stored could you please provide the solution for this code

```
 public class Common 

  {

    private static final String LAN_STORE_KEY = "lan_store_key" ;
public static void setAppLanguage(Context context, String lang) {
        //APP_LANG = lang;

        Editor editor =
            context.getSharedPreferences(LAN_STORE_KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        editor.putString("key", lang);
        editor.commit();

        System.out.println("getAppLanguage(getApplicationContext()===inside set==>"+getAppLanguage(context));
    }

    public static String getAppLanguage(Context context) {
        //return APP_LANG;
        SharedPreferences savedSession =
        context.getSharedPreferences(LAN_STORE_KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //System.out.println("getAppLanguage(getApplicationContext()===inside get==>"+getAppLanguage(context));
        return savedSession.getString(LAN_STORE_KEY, "") ;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "but in this language is not stored "?

Comment: yes language is not stored could you please provide the solution for this